# IAsyncInterceptor stuck in recursive loop

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, interceptor, castle

I'm following an approach to intercept a simple method asynchronously: https://github.com/wswind/Learn-AOP/blob/master/AutofacAsyncInterceptor/CallLoggerAsyncInterceptor.cs

For the sake of this question, a reduced version of this code could be:

```cs
private async Task<TResult> InternalInterceptAsynchronous<TResult>(IInvocation invocation)
{
    // do some async stuff
    // invoke the original method
    invocation.Proceed();
    var task = (Task<TResult>)invocation.ReturnValue;
    var result = await task;
    return result;
}
```

I did think prior to implementing this that it'd be recursive - since `invocation.Proceed()` would then be intercepted again, which would itself invoke the `Proceed()` again, and so on and so forth.

I've seen many recommendations on SO of this library, and it's widely accepted as an approach to intercepting async, what am I missing that would make this method *not* recursive? It's stuck in an infinite loop, but to me that's expected.

### Edit

I discovered what this is, narrowed it down to the 'async stuff' being something like the following:

```cs
await MyAsyncMethod();
```

When `MyAsyncMethod` is:

```cs
public async Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
   // await somethingElse();
}
```

When I'm awaiting a task that then itself awaits, it breaks `invocation.Proceed()` and I'm stuck in a loop.

Any help on this greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like `invocation.Proceed()` may be [blocking](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: @GSerg - thanks for the reply! I did read this article yday funnily enough - but rather than it locking and it freezing up it actually just loops back to the start of this method. And then invokes itself again. It's as though `invocation.Proceed` changes it's behaviour based on the fact there are 2 or more asyncs. If I changed my `somethingElse` to execute synchronously (i.e. `.Result`), it all works fine. But I don't want to do that for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

also can try https://fs7744.github.io/Norns.Urd/index.html

it use simple way to support async

```
public class AddTenInterceptorAttribute : AbstractInterceptorAttribute
{
    public override void Invoke(AspectContext context, AspectDelegate next)
    {
        next(context);
        AddTen(context);
    }

    private static void AddTen(AspectContext context)
    {
        if (context.ReturnValue is int i)
        {
            context.ReturnValue = i + 10;
        }
        else if(context.ReturnValue is double d)
        {
            context.ReturnValue = d + 10.0;
        }
    }

    public override async Task InvokeAsync(AspectContext context, AsyncAspectDelegate next)
    {
        await next(context);
        AddTen(context);
    }
}


[AddTenInterceptor]
public interface IGenericTest<T, R> : IDisposable
{
    // or
    //[AddTenInterceptor]
    T GetT();
}
```